# Difference keyboardDidShow and keyboardWillShow

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikeyboard, nsnotifications

I have a question. What is the difference between `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardWillShow`? If I put this in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

What does it mean? Sorry if this is a simple question, but I am not sure. If I enable the rotation of my view, then `keyboardDidShow` is called twice.

Another question: `keyboardWillHide?` What is its functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`keyboardWillShow` is fired before the keyboard appears, `keyboardDidShow` is fired afterwards.

`KeyboardWillHide` is fired before the keyboard disappears.

Comment: Thanks but why during rotation keyboardDidShow is called?

Comment: Is the keyboard visible at the time?

Comment: I *think* what effectively happens is that the portrait keyboard will hide, and then a landscape keyboard will appear...

Comment: No worries, can you accept the answer if you are happy with it? Thanks.